# Font awsome with same unicode

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have the following css:

```
p.word::after{
  content:  " \f111 \f111";
  font-family: "fontawesome";
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  float: right;
}
```

\f111 is the unicode value for a circle. In the font awesome we have two circles, one filled and other empty. I would like the first filled and the second one empty, but the unicode is the same for both of them.

- https://fontawesome.com/icons/circle?style=solid
- https://fontawesome.com/icons/circle?style=regular

UPDATE:

My question is how to use two different icons in the same content pseudolement. It is not possible.

SOLUTION:

The only solution for me is to create two pseudoelements: a before pseudoelement with solid and a after pseudolement with regular.

```
p.word::before{
  content:  " \f111";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  float: right;
}

p.word::after{
  content:  " \f111";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: the difference is the font-weight

Comment: I know, but I can´t find the solution for the content.

Comment: use both pseudo element, you cannot with the same

Answer (score 1):

For Solid Circle

```
p.word::after{
  content:  " \f111";
  font-family: "fontawesome";
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  float: right;
  font-weight:900;     /* Add this */
}
```

For Regular Circle

```
p.word::after{
  content:  " \f111";
  font-family: "fontawesome";
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  float: right;
  font-weight:200;    /* Add this */
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to set the class in the content.

Comment: try my updated code. font-weight is the matter for both